# How to use String.startWith(..) to ignore leading whitespace?

Tags: java, regex, string

Let's say I have the following that start with `needle`, ignoring leading whitespace:

```
String haystack = "needle#####^&%#$^%...";
String haystackWithSpace = "    needle******!@@#!@@%@%!$...";
```

I want to capture anything that starts with `needle` or `^\s*needle.*` (if there was a regex allowed). Is there an elegant way to do this without calling `trim()`? Or is there a way to make a regex work here? I want the following to be true:

```
haystackWithSpace.startsWith("needle"); // doesn't ignore leading whitespace
haystackWithSpace.startsWith("^\\s*needle"); // doesn't work
```

Basically, is there a String `s` that will satisfy the following?:

```
haystack.startsWith(s) == haystackWithSpace.startsWith(s);
```

Comment: You can use regex with the `^` special character to indicate start of String.

Comment: what about `trim()` the string before `startsWith()`?, or you could `Patther pat = Patter.compile('^needle')` and `Matcher mat = pat.matcher(<yourString>);`

Comment: `java.util.regex.Pattern.matches("^\\s*needle.*", "    needleBlahBlah")` evaluates to true.

Comment: 1) startsWith does not accept regular expressions 2) that isn't a valid regex anyway :>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```java
s.matches("^\\\\s*" + Pattern.quote("string I'm matching"))
```

Or precompile the pattern:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\\\s*" + Pattern.quote("string I'm matching"));
if (p.matcher(s).matches()) { ... }
```

Comment: You should be using `Matcher.find()` for this.  `matches()` requires the regex to cover the whole string, and we're only interested in the beginning part.  Either that, or pad the end of the regex with `.*`, as one of the commenters suggested.

Comment: The anchor forces it to the beginning of the string, so it shouldn't go looking elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to trim leading and trailing whitespace

```
string=string.trim();
```

Comment: +1 This is the better answer. [No need to whip out regex if you don't have to](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the regex `^\s+` with `""`, all whitespace will be removed from the start of the string.

```
haystack = haystack.replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
```